# How to remove city filed from checkout page magento 2?

Tags: checkout, shipping-address, billing-address, magento2.1.0

I want to remove city field from the shipping and billing form on the checkout page. I have checked in **checkout_index_index.xml** in my theme or vendor but I didn't find the city field.

Give me suggestion to remove City field.

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct syntax to disable the City field without breaking anything else, following the ["disable a component documentation"](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/howdoi/checkout/checkout_customize.html)

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="city" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

Comment: I added checout_index_index.xml  file in my them but not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try with following code in **checkout_index_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
  <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
    <arguments>
    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">                                 

                             <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="billingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                             <!-- The name of the form the field belongs to -->
                                                <item name="billing -address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <!--Remove fields-->
                                                        <item name="city" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                            <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <!-- The name of the form the field belongs to -->
                                            <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <!--Remove fields-->
                                                    <item name="city" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
   </arguments>
  </referenceBlock>
 </body>
</page>
```

Comment: after using this code, city field has removed but getting error on placing order. Error: an error occured on server. Please try again to order place.

Comment: @VinodKumar  did you find the solution for your error?. I'm also getting that error, please share your solution here..